# Permission denied on MS Word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an MS Word document (Office 365 version 1803) with a large number of images.  I need to select all images in the document, but there are far too many to do this by hand.  Looking online, it seems the only way to do this is using a macro, which I have no experience with.  I wrote the following very simple macro:

```
Sub SelectAllImages()
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
End Sub
```

When I saved the document, I was forced to change it to a macro-enabled Word document (.docm), which I did.  However, whenever I try to run the macro I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '70': Permission denied
```

I have Googled this error, but nothing has helped me fix it.  Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: As additional data, what I'm trying to do is delete most but not all of the images.  I have a document that is 200+ pages long with an average of about 1 image per page.  I need to publish 2 versions of this document: 1 with all images, the second with all but about 12 of the images removed.  The document is updated regularly, and I don't want to have to keep updating 2 separate versions and ensure they are identical except for the inclusion of the images.  Thus I'd like to be able to maintain only one version, which includes all the images.  Then after each update I'd like to be able to select all the images, manually unselect the 12 I want to keep, and delete the others.

If there is a way to somehow "tag" the images I want to keep and have a macro delete all but the tagged ones that would be an even better solution.

Comment: I can't repro the problerm using the steps you describe... Try: 1) restart Windows and Word; 2) write the macro in  a new document and save as docm; 3) close the document, close Word; 4) start Word, open the document, insert some shapes and test the macro.

Comment: You will get that error if there are any InlineShapes in the document. There only has to be one and that command will error out. You will have to select InlineShapes separately from Shapes with wrapping text. What exactly are you trying to do with the selected shapes?

Comment: @Rich Michaels: I just did some testing and it seems you're right--the error only occurs if one or more of the images are set to inline wrapping.  Any idea how to select all inline images in the document plus all non-inline ones?  I edited the question to add additional info about what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that error if there are any InlineShapes in the document. There only has to be one and that command will error out. You will have to select InlineShapes separately from Shapes with wrapping text. See code below.

Concerning your question about tagging. To "Tag" the images put a unique phrase like "Do Not Delete" in the Alt Text of the images. Then you can use code like the below to remove all images, except those that have been tagged.

For Inline Images this code will potentially leave a blank paragraph in the document and I will leave that to you to figure out how you want the final document to look.

```
Sub RemoveAllImagesWithExceptions()
Dim doc As Word.Document, iShp As Word.InlineShape
Dim shp As Word.Shape, i As Long, rng As Word.Range
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set rng = doc.Content
For i = rng.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set iShp = rng.InlineShapes(i)
    Select Case iShp.Type
        Case wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture, wdInlineShapePicture
            If InStr(1, iShp.AlternativeText, "Do Not Delete") = 0 Then
                iShp.Delete
            End If
    End Select
Next
For i = rng.ShapeRange.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set shp = rng.ShapeRange(i)
    Select Case shp.Type
        Case msoLinkedPicture, msoPicture
            If InStr(1, shp.AlternativeText, "Do Not Delete") = 0 Then
                shp.Delete
            End If
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!  Since the question was regarding why I was getting the permission error, you may want to include the bit about it being caused by inline images at the beginning.